# Calculating % Return in Pairs Trading Strategy

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, trading, pairs-trading

Hi guys Could you help me here?

I would like to calculate the return of a Pairs Trading strategy. For example:

18/11 - Open the Trade: I will go long on A and Short on B:

Stock A : $ 32.24
Stock B : $ 29.82

Ratio: $\frac{(Price of StockA)}{(Price of StockB)} = 1,0812$

I will buy:
$\frac{($30.000)}{32.24} = 900$ (approximately)) units of Stock A. 
The cost is: $900*32.24 = \$29,016.00$

And Sell:
$\frac{($30.000)}{29.82} = 1000$ (approximately)) units of Stock B : $ = 1000*29.82 = \$29,820.00$

The Cost of Open the Trade:$ \$29,820.00 - \$29,016.00 = \$804 $

---

At 20/11 I will **Close** the Trade:

Price of Stock A At 20/11: $ \$32.63$
Price of Stock B At 20/11: $ \$30.08$

Ratio: $\frac{(Price of StockA)}{Price of StockB} = 1,0848$

I will sell $900$ units of Stocks A: $900*32.63 = \$29,367$ and
I will buy  $1000$ units of Stock B: $1000*30.08 = \$30,080$

The cost of Close the Trade: $ \$29,367 - \$30,080 = -\$713$

---

To calculate Profit/Loss of this strategy I just sum the **The cost of Open the Trade** and **The cost of Close the Trade** which is $\$91$ on this case.

**My question is: How can I calculate the $\%$ return of this strategy?**

But I've been reading and it got a little confusing for me.

Many thanks!

Comment: Short answer is that the return equals P&L divided by your equity. Long answer = longwinded proof of concept gladly given, if required :-) Had you doubled the size of your pairs trade, would that change the % return? Done millions rather than thousands? If not, you’re getting into concepts of return that have no intuitive meaning to mainstream investors. Happy to explain, if useful.

Comment: @demully you mean by shor answer this: $ \frac{(\$91)}{\$29,016.00}$ ? I didnt understand the long answer part.

Comment: The problem you face is that the long and the short are self-financing. You borrow X to sell X worth of the short to give you X cash to finance X's worth of your long. Which gives you a profit or loss of Y. This is only meaningful in % terms compared to the Z capital you have to risk this P&L. The same Y P&L for investors with more or less Z to support this position leads to different "% returns".

Comment: @demully On this link the author calculates the return in a different way. Do you mind take a look?  https://analyticsprofile.com/algo-trading/pair-trading-part-2-code-correlation-based-pair-trading-strategy-in-r/ . This is how he calculates it: `spread_return <- ret_stock1 - ret_stock2*hedge_ratio`-
`trade_return <- spread_return*signal` .

Comment: Ah OK... his "returns" are expressed in unit terms, not % terms ;-) His nice chart is just my Y, ie P&L, given his position sizing. The % return you seek is a function of this AND how much capital you have to bear said risk. That is the ungiven, for all of us.

Comment: @demully yes!! Now I got it! Many many thanks for your time!

Comment: @demully So, using your argument how do I compare a month's return between pair trading, bonds return, stock portfolio returns, currencies returns and etc?

Comment: Now that's the basis for a question in it's own right, to which I promise I will attempt a proper answer, beyond comments to clarify comments :-)